# Hide Login Page Labels

Tags: css, login

I am trying to hide the labels for username and password on wordpress login page. I tried with no luck.

```
body.login div#login form#loginform p label {display: none;}
p.login-username label, p.login-password label {display: none;}
```

Any ideas? I can't seem to find a specific selector just for the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this workaround but not very neat I guess..

```
.login label {
    font-size: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: [Here is](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214063/5549) another option